# SyntaxWarning: name 'item' is assigned to before global declaration global item

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new to python and am trying to make a basic shopping list program as a starting project.

The output and error I get on running is :

```
Please enter item number 1:

scratch_3.py:29: SyntaxWarning: name 'item' is assigned to before global declaration
  global item
```

Can someone please explain why I am getting this issue and/or a better way to achieve the same result?

```
num = 1
item = input('Please enter item number ' + str(num) + ': ')
my_list = [item]
del_list = []

def _delete_ ():
    global my_list
    global del_list
    global num
    global item
    if item == 'DELETE':
        delitem = my_list.pop()
        del_list.append(delitem)
        print('You have successfully deleted ' + delitem + ' from your shopping list')
        num = num - 1

def _add_to_list_():
    global item
    global my_list
    global num
    item = input('Please enter item number ' + str(num) + ': ')
    my_list.append(item)
    num = num + 1
    print(my_list)


while item != 'STOP':
    global item
    if item == 'DELETE':
        _delete_()
    else:
        _add_to_list_()
```

Comment: You should't be declaring `global item` inside your loop.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed the error!

Answer (score 12):

According to [Python's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement):

> Names listed in a global statement must not be used in the same code block textually preceding that global statement.
>
> Names listed in a global statement must not be defined as formal parameters or in a for loop control target, class definition, function definition, import statement, or variable annotation.

You shouldn't be declaring `global item` inside your loop. Anyway, as you already are in the same scope as your `item` declaration in there, you can simply access it.

I think it will help you to understand [what are the rules for local and global variables in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python).

Comment: Furthermore, a better understanding of Python's scopes and local vs global variable will help you to improve the functions you already have. You don't need all the `global` declarations you're making. And you should considering avoiding the ones you do need to make your code work as it is (if you don't really understand the effects of declaring everything global).