# SyntaxError: name 'retry' is assigned to before global declaration

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, syntax-error, global-variables

It keeps saying this: SyntaxError: name 'retry' is assigned to before global declaration

Any tips as to how I can fix this?

This is the code:

```
import time

global retry 
retry = 1

def message(pausetime, text):
        print(text)
        time.sleep(pausetime)

def investigate(var):
        print("You find" +" "+ var)

def death():
    lose = input(" You lost, would you like to try again? n\ press y to try again or n to stop playing ")
    if lose == "y":
        global retry 
        retry = 1
    elif lose == "n":
        print("Thanks for playing! Hope you enjoyed")
        global retry 
        retry = 0

def win():
    print("Congratulations! You defeated the Orc King and stopped the Orc raids, you are now the hero of Everwood!")
    global retry 
    retry = 0

while retry >= 1:
#some code
```

It says the problem is in line 20 which just says:

```
global retry
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SyntaxWarning: name 'item' is assigned to before global declaration global item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53528532/syntaxwarning-name-item-is-assigned-to-before-global-declaration-global-item)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `global retry` before declaring `retry` in the global scope (`retry` is *already* in the global scope). Just remove that.

```
import time

# global retry <= not necessary
retry = 1

...
```

Also, it's only necessary to use `global retry` once within the definition of `death()`, like so

```
def death():
    global retry
    lose = input(" You lost, would you like to try again? n\ press y to try again or n to stop playing ")
    if lose == "y":
        retry = 1
    elif lose == "n":
        print("Thanks for playing! Hope you enjoyed")
        retry = 0
```

More info: The `global` keyword is used inside functions to allow them to modify variables that exist in the global scope (e.g., `retry`). Naturally, functions that don't need to modify this value don't need to set `global retry`